# Streamwriter issue with remote machine

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to create a file on the remote machine but I am getting The "Network name cannot be found". I checked the network path and I was able to access the path from my machine. Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

Here is my code.

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\\\\servername\\TEST1\\TEST\\NEWFILE.csv", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(sw);
    }
```

Comment: Is your program running under your user or under a service account?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code.  You need to figure out what the full path to the file is then simply use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the access rights to the user under which this application runs either it is a IIS pool or windows service etc

Answer (score 1):

Go to \servername\TEST1 and give write permission to the user or aspnet (if you have a web application) on ***test*** folder and then re-run your program. It will work.

To give write permissions, just refer to this article:
[How to share a folder/File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)

In case it still does not work, replace servername with server IP address and do the same as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

it is surely a security isssue. you need to give Write access to the remote machine